# MVC3 ..what makes the Html.ValidationMessage ...display a "*" on render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, data-annotations

C#, MVC3, Razor

Is there an easy way to display a "*" when Razor view renders
and then apply a different (more informative) message when the 
actual validation takes place?

The view is currently using
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)

The more informative validation is already there, but i don't have the "*" showing that 
certain fields are required.

QUESTION:
Am I missing something that i can add on the DataAnnotation so that it "also" add that [*] at the end of each required TextBox on the view ?

===================================
I could create a new HTMLExtension like:

```
    public static partial class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RequiredSymbolFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            string symbol = "*",
            string cssClass = "editor-field-required")
        {
            ModelMetadata modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

            if (modelMetadata.IsRequired)
            {
                var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
                builder.AddCssClass(cssClass);
                builder.InnerHtml = symbol;

                return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }
    }
```

...and then just add the new htmlhelper on the view as:

```
@Html.RequiredSymbolFor(model => model.Firstname)
```

from [http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2011/08/26/an-htmlhelper-to-display-if-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-aspnet-mvc-3/]

but I was just wondering if there is easier way.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

why not just put the asterisk in the view after each textbox?
as in
 `@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.CommentAuthorName) *`

Comment: I was hoping not to hard coded that way ..I'm mainly looking to see if there is a param Im missing on that ValidationMessageFor. Plus if you do it your way, the * remains even after the validation message gets displayed.

Comment: It's not a good idea, cause you need to manuly type "*" for each field with Required property.